# Почему игнорируется handler погоды в aiogram Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

Игнорируются два последних хендлера о выводе погоды, почему ? До них код выполняется, aiogram python.
Вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands= ['get_info', 'info'] )
async def get_user_info(message: types.Message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'да' , callback_data= 'yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'нет' , callback_data= 'no')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Желаете узнать инфо о вас ?' ,
          reply_markup= markup_inline
    )



@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data)
async def answer(call:types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data == 'yes' :
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_id = types.KeyboardButton( ' МОЙ ID')
        item_username = types.KeyboardButton ( ' МОЙ НИК')

        markup_reply.add(item_id, item_username)
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Нажмите на одну из конопок',
               reply_markup = markup_reply
)
    elif call.data == 'no' :
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ну и ладно'),



@dp.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])   # Приветствие!
async def get_start(message):
    if message.text == 'Привет':
         sti = open('welcome.webp', 'rb')
         await bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
         await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(message.from_user, await bot.get_me()),
             parse_mode='html')
    elif message.text == 'МОЙ ID':
          await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  f'Ваш ID: {message.from_user.id}')
    elif message.text == 'МОЙ НИК' :
          await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  f'Ваш Ник: {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}')


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! напиши мне название города и я пришлю сводку погоды!")


@dp.message_handler()
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    code_to_smile = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_key}&units=metric"
        )
        data = r.json()

        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

        weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        if weather_description in code_to_smile:
            wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"

        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["sys"]["sunrise"])

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
              f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n"
              f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с\n"
              f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
              f"***Хорошего дня***"
              )




    except:
        await message.reply("\U00002620 Проверьте название города \U00002620")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передал ваш код. Прежде чем копировать прочитайте до конца. ПОЖАЛУЙСТА не делайте как в телеботе! Айограм имеет прекрасную систему фильтров, которую НУЖНО использовать. Хватит этих ваших ИФОВ! Хватит этих ЛЯМБДА=TRUE! ПРОШУ АСТАНАВИТЕСЬ!
Собственно. Так как ваша реализация кода была слишком... неправильной, то соответственно у вас что-то могло не работать. Я поменял в большинстве мест, вместо вашего любимого лямбда=ТРУ на адекватное условия типа text="тыры-пыры".
Что делает этот параметр? Всё просто. Если сообщение или колбек дата будет равна этому параметру то он срабатывает. Все. И никаких тебе лямбда=ТРУ, черт возьми.

Ну и для информации существуют еще несколько хороших фильтров.
text - только точное совпадение
text_startwith - текст начинается с
text_endswith - текст заканчивается на
text_contains - текст содержит определенный текст

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['get_info', 'info'])
async def get_user_info(message: types.Message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='да', callback_data='yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='нет', callback_data='no')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Желаете узнать инфо о вас ?',
                           reply_markup=markup_inline)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="yes")
async def answer_yes(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item_id = types.KeyboardButton(' МОЙ ID')
    item_username = types.KeyboardButton(' МОЙ НИК')

    markup_reply.add(item_id, item_username)
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Нажмите на одну из конопок',
                           reply_markup=markup_reply)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="no")
async def answer_no(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ну и ладно'),


@dp.message_handler(text="Привет")  # Приветствие!
async def hi_message(message: types.Message):
    sti = open('welcome.webp', 'rb')
    await bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
    await bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        text=f"Добро пожаловать, {message.from_user.first_name}!\n"
             f"Я - <b>{(await bot.get_me()).first_name}</b>, "
             f"бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.",
        parse_mode='html')


@dp.message_handler(text="МОЙ ID")  # Приветствие!
async def send_my_id(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ID: {message.from_user.id}')


@dp.message_handler(text="МОЙ НИК")  # Приветствие!
async def get_start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш Ник: {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}')


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! напиши мне название города и я пришлю сводку погоды!")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["weather"])
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    code_to_smile = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_key}&units=metric"
        )
        data = r.json()

        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

        weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        if weather_description in code_to_smile:
            wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"

        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["sys"]["sunrise"])

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
                            f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n"
                            f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с\n"
                            f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
                            f"***Хорошего дня***"
                            )




    except:
        await message.reply("\U00002620 Проверьте название города \U00002620")
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь всё понятно.

Answer (score 1):

@dp.message_handler(content_types = ['text']) должен быть последним хендлером. После него другие хендлеры не обрабатываются. Это так сказать воронка, которая обрабатывает данные, которые не прошли по нужным параметрам в другие.

Comment: сделал последним, теперь кроме погоды все игнорируется. Работает только запрос на погоду, даже если вызывать другие хендлеры.

Comment: Сделай один хендлер @dp.message_handler(content_types = ['text']) и там уже ищи нужные слова. if message.text == 'МОЙ ID': await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ID: {message.from_user.id}') elif message.text == 'МОЙ НИК': await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш Ник: {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}')